# What is the difference between GenericServlet, HttpServlet and a Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I was searching for exact difference between `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`
, `javax.servlet.GenericServlet` and `javax.Servlet` unable to find it out.

"Exact Difference" means

1. Usage
2. Reason behind `javax.servlet.GenericServlet` existence

Comment: That's just already answered in their javadocs. Did you read it? [Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html), [GenericServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html) and [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

Answer (score 28):

"Exact difference" meaning what? The API lists the *exact* differences.

[`Servlet` is an interface defining what a servlet must implement.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html)

[`GenericServlet` is just that, a generic, protocol-independent servlet.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html)

[`HttpServlet` is a servlet tied specifically to the HTTP protocol.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

Are you asking when you'd *use* any of those?

In general, you'd extend `HttpServlet` to implement an application's web layer.

You might implement `Servlet` if you're writing your own container or handling everything yourself. You might extend `GenericServlet` to handle a different protocol, but you might not.

Comment: +1 for `You might implement Servlet if you're writing your own container or handling everything yourself`

Answer (score 14):

**javax.servlet**

Servlet is a server-side web technology. As the name implies, it serves a client request and receives a response from the server. You have to implement javax.Servlet (Interface) to handle a servlet work.

**javax.servlet.GenericServlet**

*Signature:*

```
public abstract class GenericServlet extends java.lang.Object implements Servlet, ServletConfig, java.io.Serializable
```

1. GenericServlet defines a generic, protocol-independent servlet.
2. GenericServlet gives a blueprint and makes writing servlet easier.
3. GenericServlet provides simple versions of the life-cycle methods
   init and destroy and of the methods in the ServletConfig interface.
4. GenericServlet implements the log method, declared in the
   ServletContext interface.
5. To write a generic servlet, it is sufficient to override the
   abstract service() method.

**javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet**

*Signature:*

```
public abstract class HttpServlet extends GenericServlet implements java.io.Serializable
```

1. HttpServlet defines a HTTP protocol specific servlet.
2. HttpServlet gives a blueprint for Http servlet and makes writing
   them easier.
3. HttpServlet extends the GenericServlet and hence inherits the
   properties GenericServlet.

Comment: This answer is taken from http://javapapers.com/servlet/difference-between-httpservlet-and-genericservlet/

Comment: best answer for me

Answer (score 12):

[javax.servlet.Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) is interface, it defines methods for all the implementations - that's what interfaces usually do.

[javax.servlet.GenericServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html) is protocol independent. It is abstract, so it is not to be directly instantiated. It is usable class to extend if you some day have to write servlet for protocol other than HTTP.

[javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) is abstract class to be extended if you want to communicate over HTTP protocol. Most likely you only have to care about this one.

More exact information you can find behind the links.

Answer (score 8):

-> One common feature is, both these Classes are Abstract Classes.

-> GenericServlet is a super class of HttpServlet class.

-> The main difference is that, HttpServlet is a protocol dependent whereas GenericServlet is protocol independent. So GenericServlet can handle all types of protocols, but HttpServlet handle only HTTP specific protocols.

-> GenericServlet belongs to javax.servlet package. HttpServlet belongs to javax.servlet.http package

-> GenericServlet is an abstract class which extends Object and implements Servlet, ServletConfig and java.io.Serializable interfaces. HttpServlet is an abstract class which extends GenericServlet and implements java.io.Serializable interface.

-> GenericServlet supports only service() method does not contain doGet() and doPost() methods. HttpServlet support also doGet(), doPost(), doHead() methods (HTTP 1.0) plus doPut(), doOptions(), doDelete(), doTrace() methods (HTTP 1.1).

Answer (score 4):

Servlet:-

1. The Servlets runs as a thread in a web-container instead of in a seperate OS process.
2. Only one object is created first time when first request comes, other request share the same object.
3. Servlet is platform independent.
4. Servlet is fast.

GenericServlet:-

1. General for all protocol.
2. Implements Servlet Interface.
3. Use Service method.

HttpServlet:-

1. Only for HTTP Protocol.
2. Inherit GenericServlet class.
3. Use doPost, doGet method instead of service method.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpServlet` is specific to the HTTP protocol and hence it supplies methods for the HTTP verbs: `doGet`, `doPost`, etc, and a version of the generic `service` method that takes HTTP-specific request and response objects. It is a special type of `Servlet` which is actually a pretty minimal interface.

`GenericServlet` is the basic, protocol-neutral implementation of the `Servlet` interface. Often you'll find similar basic implementations of interfaces in an API; in this case `GenericServlet` adds a bit of functionality to the `Servlet` API: `getServletName`, `getServletInfo`, and pass-through methods for the servlet init parameters. `HttpServlet` benefits from these additions by extending `GenericServlet`.

Generally everyone coding against this API is using `HttpServlet` for implementing HTTP web services, but one can also extend or use `GenericServlet` for implementing server/service functionality using a custom protocol, or another extant protocol, for example, FTP.

Answer (score 2):

Servlet is an interface which contains five abstract methods in order use servlet we have to provide an implementation for all these five methods, which is a headache. In order to avoid this complexity, we have GenericServlet and HttpServlet for next level.

GenericServlet is protocol independent, it means it can accept any protocol request.
GenericServlet can forward and include a request but we can not redirect the request.
Session Management with cookies and HttpSession is not possible in GenericServlet.
In GenericServlet it is not possible to define separate logic for get and post request.

HttpServlet is protocol dependent. it means, it accepts only HTTP protocol request.
HttpServlet can forward and include and redirect a request.
Session Management with cookies and HttpSession is possible in HttpServlet.
In HttpServlet it is possible to define separate logic for get and post request.

Comment: I like your answer.
Please like my answer also.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Servlet interface**
   Its the super interface for **GenericServlet** and **HttpServlet**. It contains 5 abstract methods and all inherited by GenericServlet and HttpServlet.

   - **Problem**

     If you want to create servlet by implementing Servlet interface all the 5 abstract methods of the interface Servlet should be overridden eventhough Programmer is not interested
   - **Usage**

     Only implement Servlet interface if you like to develop your own container.
2. **GenericServlet**
   Its the immediate subclass of Servlet interface and super class of HttpServlet. In this class, one abstract method exist: service(). Other 4 abstract methods are implemented in this class.

   - **Problem**

     All methods are concrete except service() method, So you have to implement it as a callback method.
   - **Usage**

     It is protocol independent so Can be used with any protocol like FTP, SMTP, HTTP etc.
3. **HttpServlet**
   Its subclass of both GenericServlet and Servlet interface. Immediate super class of HttpServlet is GenericServlet. HttpServlet does not contain any abstract method. Eventhough the HttpServlet does not contain any abstract methods, it is declared as abstract class by the Designers to not to allow the anyone to create an object directly because a Servlet object is created by the Servlet Container.

   - **Problem**

     HttpServlet is protocol dependent and used specific to HTTP protocol only.
   - **Usage**

     service() method need not be overridden. It can be replaced by doGet() or doPost() methods with the same parameters. Its most used method to create servlet.
     [hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD0qh.png)

     Reference: [way2java.com](https://way2java.com/)

Answer (score 1):

-->`GenericServlet` can process multiple clients request from a single form. Whereas, `HttpServlet` can process multiple clients requesting from multiple `HTML` forms.

--> `GenericServlet` is Stateless and `HttpServlet` is Stateful.

Answer (score 0):

All classes, interfaces, and methods present in the `javax.servlet` package are protocol *independent* (generic to all protocols).

In contrast, all classes, interfaces, and methods present in the `javax.servlet.http` package are protocol *dependent* (specific to the HTTP protocol)

Answer (score 0):

1. http servlet is an class which is specific and allows only http protocol not allowed to other protocol like ftp smtp
2. generic servlet are allowed all types of protocol only one abstract method that is service method and other four method are concrete  method
3. generic servlet is the superclass of http servlet