# servlet error The requested resource () is not available

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to servlets .I am using eclipse juno for this.I am having a  trouble in running my program..My code is

```
package sTraining;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class Servlet1 implements Servlet{
ServletConfig config=null;

public void init(ServletConfig config){
this.config=config;
System.out.println("servlet is initialized");
}

public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)
throws IOException,ServletException{

res.setContentType("text/html");

PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
out.print("<html><body>");
out.print("<b>hello simple servlet</b>");
out.print("</body></html>");

}
public void destroy(){System.out.println("servlet is destroyed");}
public ServletConfig getServletConfig(){return config;}
public String getServletInfo(){return "copyright 2007-1010";}

}
```

I am getting this error[http://localhost:8080/Test/WEB-INF/classes/sTraining/Servlet1.java][1]
 although i have this thing in my web .xml file

```xml
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Servlet1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.Servlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

why this is not running? My code is fine. First time when I run this page it run, but running this program after my second program it did not run and that second program also not run.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you accessing

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/WEB-INF/classes/sTraining/Servlet1.java
```

? You should be accessing

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/Servlet1
```

Read the above as

```
[protocol or scheme] :// [host] : [port] / [context] / [servlet mapping]
```

Also, according to the source code you've posted. The `Servlet1` class is in package `sTraining`. Your `web.xml` should therefore have

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Servlet1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>sTraining.Servlet1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

A `Servlet` Container will not make anything in the `WEB-INF` folder available to client requests.

---

What you are doing is not great practice. Your class should probably extend `HttpServlet` to get some standard HTTP behavior. You also shouldn't be writing HTML in Java code. Try reading the tutorial and references we have on Stackoverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: You could also add that every file inside WEB-INF folder cannot be accessed through a client

Comment: *your class should extend `HttpServlet` to get some standard behavior* this applies for beginners on the matter, but when creating a framework like Spring MVC or JSF, it is better to implement the `Servlet` interface than extending from `HttpServlet`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't know for JSF, but Spring's `DispatcherServlet` extends `HttpServlet` somewhere in its inheritance tree. What would you recommend I put instead? Go ahead and edit the answer. I'll wiki it.

Comment: As said, if you want to create a MVC framework, your servlet should implement the `Servlet` interface instead of just extending `HttpServlet` in order to manage everything by yourself. This is better explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11530152/1065197

Comment: this also give me same result

Comment: @user2502227 Your class' package is `sTraining`. The `servlet-class` should be `sTraining.Servlet1` instead of `servlet.Servlet1`.

Answer (score 1):

Put `./Servlet1` in your form action attribute

```
<form action="./Servlet1">
....
</form>
```

and check your `web.xml`
your package name is different

```
    <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Servlet1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>sTraining.Servlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: *Put ./Servlet1 in your form action attribute* OP is accessing the servlet through a GET request, this will work if OP wants to submit data from JSP to this servlet.

Comment: yes i know,i have mention the way. if OP wants to request through JSP or HTML